# NestJs Validation Pipe dosent return any message

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

In NestJs I can not figure out how can get the validaiton error message from ValidationPipe. Always send generic response that includes no "message" parameter like this. :

```json
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "timestamp": "2021-05-22T09:59:27.708Z",
  "path": "/batchs"
}
```

In main.ts I put the pipeline defination

```js
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
```

And this my dto

```js
export class BatchCreateDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'username is required' })
    code: string;

    @ApiProperty({ type: Lang })
    title: Lang;

    @ApiProperty({ type: Lang })
    description: Lang;

    @ApiProperty()
    startingDate: Date;

    @ApiProperty()
    duraitonInHours: number;


}
```

If I send data with emty "code" field to api, the api returns generic  Bad Request response that not includes message parameter. If the "code" field contains any data, there is no problem, api insert object to database. So I understand that validation pipe works, but why does not return any detailed message if validation fails.
I want to get the message parameter that includes something like "username is required" or any generic message. Thanks for help.

UPDATE
Body of the request that causes error

```json
{
  "code": "",
  "title": {
    "en": "this is test",
    "tr": "bu testtir"
  },
  "description": {
    "en": "some explination...",
    "tr": "bazı açıklamalar..."
  },
  "startingDate": "2021-05-24T07:51:03.197Z",
  "duraitonInHours": 14
}
```

BatchController uses BatchCreateDto

```js
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Post, Put, Query, UsePipes, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BatchService } from '../services/batch.service';
import { ApiBody, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { BatchCreateDto } from 'src/entities/dto/batch.create.dto';

@ApiTags('Batchs')
@Controller('batchs')
export class BatchController {
    constructor(private batchService: BatchService) { }

    @Post()
    public async addBatch(@Body() batch: BatchCreateDto) {
        const result = await this.batchService.add(batch);
        return result;
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you please post the body of the request that reproduce this error?

Comment: Could you show the import statement for BatchCreateDto where you use it?

Comment: Hi @SPS and Eranga Heshan. Thanks for your replies. I have just updated my question. Anymore your requests are in it.

Comment: @ZiyaSarı Check if you have anything changing the response before it's returned (interceptor, guard, pipe, or filter) as the error response from validation failures is an array of messages, you may need to add a case to return arrays also.

Comment: Thank you very much  @Isolated . In main.ts the line `app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter())` causes the issue.

Comment: In that case, if you were to remove that filter, do you get the correct response? @Ziya Sarı

Comment: Yes. I created a custom validation filter and removed the generic HttpExceptionFilter in app.useGlobalFilters statement. The result is what I expect. @Isolated